# Reading N bytes of data from stdin and then pipe the rest

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to essentially do this:

```js
const iv = stdin.readSync(16)
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', key, iv)
stdin.pipe(decipher).pipe(stdout)
```

Of course since there is no `readSync` this won't work. As a sanity check I tried this:

```js
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0)
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', key, iv)
stdin.pipe(decipher).pipe(stdout)
```

This "works", as it prints stuff, but of course the decryption produces garbage as it is the wrong IV.

This is the solution I'm trying to get to work:

```
// pull 16 bytes from stdin
const iv = await new Promise(resolve => {
    var gotiv = false
    stdin.on('readable', () => {
        if(gotiv) return
        const iv = stdin.read(16)
        if(iv) {
            gotiv = true
            console.error(iv)
            //stdin.pause()
            //stdin.off('readable', arguments.callee)
            resolve(iv)
        }
    })
})

// continue after those 16 bytes
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', key, iv)
return stdin.pipe(decipher).pipe(stdout)
```

This gets the IV however it does not decrypt or print anything (program exits).

It seems like there is something I don't understand about the stream state.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html.

The 'data' event is emitted whenever the stream is relinquishing ownership of a chunk of data to a consumer. The 'data' event will also be emitted whenever the readable.read() method is called and a chunk of data is available to be returned.

`chunck` is a type of Buffer(https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), and you can slice 16 bytes.

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    let body = ''
    stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk
        if (body.length >= 16) {
            resolve(body.slice(0, 16))
        }
    })
}).then((iv) => {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', key, iv)
    return stdin.pipe(decipher).pipe(stdout)
})
```

Would like to help to understand stream and buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I specifically don't use the `data` event because I need to control the amount of bytes released by the stream. It has to be `N`, not more or less. I do get 16 bytes of data when I call `const iv = stdin.read(16)`. I also need the `stdin.pipe(decipher)...` to continue exactly after those 16 bytes. When I tried your solution data got lost that got passed to the 'data' handler and not piped to `decipher`. This kind of usage is also [not recommended](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_choose_one_api_style), though I'm not sure what I should be doing instead.